# Heightmap providers for the DEM tutorial

Tags: gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi everyone,
I try the tutorial of Gazebo for heightmap DEM. Some links are dead and the tutorial cannot continue.
I look for an elevation map provider and the link with Gazebo and the GDAL library.

Is there someone with this issue too ?

Regards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/24633/heightmap-providers-for-the-dem-tutorial/) by [Tomlogan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24765/tomlogan/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 15 on 2020-03-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I found the following tutorial helpful: https://github.com/AS4SR/general_info/wiki/Creating-Heightmaps-for-Gazebo#Open_in_Gazebo.
It also points to a source for the DEM (but use it only for testing, the map gets scaled before downloading it because it is intended to be used in a computer game).

A great tool to automate the entire process to get the DEM into Gazebo is this one: https://github.com/MatthewVerbryke/gazebo_terrain

---

Originally posted by [logito](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/25239/logito/) with karma: 26 on 2020-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tomlogan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24765/tomlogan/) on 2020-04-06**:
Thanks I didn't receive a notification of your answer :(
I'm looking for something more precise but I don't think it exist. I stock the tool to automate that 2 months ago, I didn't get time to test it :P.